# OBS Studio Black Screen when capturing the screen

Tags: video, editing, obs

Why am I getting a black screen when I'm going to capture the screen using the OBS studio? I already changed the graphic card settings and the compatibility but still, it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to this problem! I think OBS studio is having some problems with the Nvidia driver updates. So I configured it to run using the onboard graphic card (Intel(R) UHD Graphics). now it is working

follow these steps:

right-click on desktop -> Display settings -> scroll down to the bottom -> Graphic settings -> Select classic app -> press browse and select the application file of OBS

[image]